# JWT token cookie being saved on postman but not in web

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

It worked fine for weeks, but for some reason, today, the cookie doesn't save on the web, even though I am getting responses from the backend and am able to save the access token on the web app. As the title says, the refresh token doesn't save on the postman.

Access token was able to save on session storage.

[image]

Refresh token doesn't save on cookie
[image]

Additionally, my axios has the setting for `withCredentials`

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default api;
```

On server, my `cors` has the setting for `credentials`

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
```

Lastly, if the login is successful, then I will be able to receive the token

```
const login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  // ... some codes here
  
  const ACCESS_TOKEN = jwt.sign(
    { user_id: userDetails.user_id, roles: userDetails.roles },
    ACCESS_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: "1hr" }
  );

  const REFRESH_TKN = jwt.sign(
    { user_id: userDetails.user_id, username: userDetails.username },
    REFRESH_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: "7d" }
  );

  res
    .cookie("REFRESH_TOKEN", REFRESH_TKN, {
      httpOnly: true,
      // secure: true, // not https yet, so comment this out for now
      sameSite: "none",
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 week (days, hours, mins, milliseconds)
    })
    .status(200)
    .send({ message: "Login successfully", token: ACCESS_TOKEN });

};
```

Here's for the postman
[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it this way [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883551/22080174)

Answer (score 0):

I verified that the requests with the definition of `withCredentials: true` already in the api sends requests for the same domain, so the problem may be in in the definition your API with axios, try creating the API with only the baseURL and passing `withCredentials: true` in the requests.

Comment: Hello! I tried it last night but this doesn't work, even commenting both credentials from backend and frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is sameSite: 'none' attribute. Due the fact it can be sent to the server with any cross-site request, so it works on secure connections only. you can comment this option and try it out and don't forget to uncomment it again along with secure option in production.

Comment: I haven't tried your suggestion but I did other thing that works for me. For some reason, setting the secure to true from cookie's option did work for me. From what I know it only works if the protocol runs on https, right? The same-site is still being set as 'none' and true for secure. Then I got the cookie also got a "lax"with value being saved on cookie. I wonder what does it mean?